# Example for when use of a constant yields smaller code than a #define

Tags: c++, constants

In his book "Effective C++ 3rd Ed." Scott Meyer writes the following two lines of code

```
#define ASPECT_RATIO 1.653
```

and

```
const double AspectRatio = 1.653;
```

and explains

"...use of the constant may yield smaller code than using a #define. That’s because the pre-processor’s  blind  substitution  of  the  macro  name ASPECT_RATIO  with 1.653  could  result  in  multiple  copies  of  1.653  in  your  object code, while the use of the constant AspectRatio should never result in more than one copy."

Is this still true for current compilers? I played a little bit around with multiple uses of constants but got the same size for both variants with a current g++. Maybe someone could show me a working example?

Thanks.

Comment: I would think today's compilers can optimize both to the same code.  That said, for C++17 and beyond, `inline constexpr auto AspectRatio = 1.653;` is my preferred way to define compile time constants.  You can even define them in header files with this technique.

Comment: `double` is probably not the best example, `const char*` seems more relevant.

Comment: I'd expect uses of `AspectRatio` to be replaced by literal `1.653` for performance, personally. Seems like a strange claim.

Comment: Yeah I'm seeing equivalent assembly in either case for a trivial example, in -O0 and -Os -O3, though admittedly it _is_ really trivial and I think you'd have to make your code much more complex to see a difference at all. https://godbolt.org/z/g2O-xM

Comment: Most notably, you will see the difference in big projects and across multiple units. Sometimes it saves a lot.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit When i don't provide *c++17* flag to compile, it generates even more assembly code in case of `const`

Comment: @KamilCuk, could you please give some quantitative example?

Comment: The statement is not correct, as there is a big dependency on the compiler and the optimization.  For example, with some processors the constants can be placed directly into the executable.  With other processors, the constant may be placed into a *data* area and loaded from the data area.  In the case of the latter, a named constant may save more code.  Also depends on the type of the numeric and the size of the numeric.  For example, the ARM processor can load small values directly with one instruction, whereas larger and unique values are stored in the data area.

Comment: With some processors, the instruction already has a field built in for the numeric value when loading into a register (a.k.a. immediate mode). In this case, there will be no savings; the value is inserted into the executable code.  In the case of the ARM processor, some values are store into a data area and then fetched indirectly (loading of the address of the data, then dereferencing the address/pointer).  Some compilers may be lazy (least optimization level) and may use indirect addressing for all numeric values (simplifies compiler construction).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...while the use of the constant AspectRatio should never result in more than one copy

More than one copy depends on many things, especially processor instruction and compiler optimization setting.  When optimizing for speed, more than one copy may lead to faster execution.  This kind of blanket statement <s>shouldn't be made</s> can't be justified or supported.

### Preprocessing

The contents of a `#define` macro are handled by the *preprocessing phase* of compilation.  The contents of the macro are inserted before the compilation (translation) begins.  With a simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#define THREE (3)
const int FOUR = 4;
int main()
{
    int value = THREE;
    std::cout << "Value is: " << value << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

After preprocessing, the compiler sees:

```
// contents of iostream header
const int FOUR = 4;
int main()
{
    int value = 3;
    std::cout << "Value is: " << value << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The `#define` macro is no different than pasting the number directly into the code.

Since the number is pasted directly into the code, the compiler deduces the type of the constant (signed vs. unsigned, integer vs. floating point), then emit code to assign the number to the variable.

### Identifiers / Symbols

When the compiler encounters the statement:

```
  const int FOUR = 4;
```

the compiler creates the symbol "FOUR" places it into a *symbol* table with the associated value of 4.  (There may be other attributes associated with the symbol, but let's keep it simple for illustrative purposes).

When the compiler encounters a statement like:

```
value = FOUR;
```

The compiler encounters the symbol "FOUR", looks it up in the *symbol* table, retrieves the value and continues processing, similar to processing the statement `value = 4;`.

### Implementation

The processor instructions emitted for either case depend on the processor and the optimization level of the compiler (and maybe the complexity of the compiler).

**Immediate Mode**
Processors have accessing or fetching modes.  For simplicity, we are concerned with *immediate* or *direct* access mode and indirect mode.  *Immediate* mode is where the instruction has field for the value.  Let's call it `MOVE` (as in move a constant into a register):

```
+--------------------------------------+    +-------+  
|         LOAD operation/instruction   |    |       |  
+--------------------+-----------------+    |       |  
+ Instruction Number | Register Number |    | Value |  
+--------------------+-----------------+    +-------+
```

The `MOVE` instruction comprises of two fields:  instruction code and the value to load into the register.  The `MOVE` instruction has two fields, always.  *Note:  The value field may be incorporated into the instruction unit (word).*

In this case, the compiler would insert the number into the value field of the instruction.  No extra space consumed, no extra instructions emitted.

**Indirect Mode**
With indirect mode, the processor loads the register via pointer (address).  The processor takes an addition step of dereferencing the pointer to fetch the value.

```
+--------------------------------------+    +---------+  
|         LOAD operation/instruction   |    | Pointer |  
+--------------------+-----------------+    |    to   |  
+ Instruction Number | Register Number |    |  Value  |  
+--------------------+-----------------+    +---------+
```

**Immediate vs. Indirect**
Some processors may have a limited range for the immediate value (for example 8-bits) and anything larger (such as `int` or `double`), would require indirect access (an addition word for the pointer/address).  Compilers, in lazy mode, could simplify operations and always use indirect mode; immediate mode would be used for higher optimization levels.

When optimizing for space, compilers may save room by using indirect mode for common constants (e.g. PI).  Using a constant variable (instead of a macro) would make this task easier.  However, a compiler may also do this with the value anyway (when it encounters 3.14159... it could store it in a table for later usage).

### Summary

The performance and size of using `#define` macro or `const` variables depends on the compiler's capabilities, optimization levels and the processor instructions.  A blanket claim that a macro is better or worse than the constant variable for space or execution speed, cannot be justified.  Too many dependencies of compiler and processor.

Common coding guidelines suggest using constant variables, as they have a type and prevent defects based on mismatched types (the compiler can issue warnings or errors).

Comment: It should be noted that techically, it looks like `int value = (3);` to the compiler. That's nit picky, though.

Comment: Otherwise, fantastic answer!